# Declare a variable for JSON

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have 3 region in my array
I display 5 JSON for each region.
How can I declare a variable for my 5 JSON ?
I add the array for region

```
var arr = [
  { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
  { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
  { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
] 

for (const key in arr) {
  var region= arr[key].region
  var Value = arr[key].value 

    cw.getMetricStatistics(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {    
    var status;

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    console.log(data.Datapoints[i]);
    // OUTPUT     
    /* (1) {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}

    (2) {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}

     (3) {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
            {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}
     */
    }


    //******* NEED *********
    tabRg = [region1, region2, region3];
}
```

My demand:

- var region1 = (1)
- var region2 = (2)
- var region3 = (3)

Comment: The question is unclear. Dou you need `tabRg = [region1, region2, region3]`, or `var region1 = (1)` ? These are two different things.

Comment: Euh I don't understand. Declare them? `var region1 = data.Datapoints[0];` ?

Comment: need var region 1 = (1) ... var region 2 = (2) ... var region 3 = (3) ...